# Reading multiple files in Windows Batch dynamically

Tags: windows, file, powershell, batch-file, cmd

My requirement might appear bit strange.

I have a list of files to read eg:
**File1.txt,File2.txt,File3.txt,File4.txt**

Also, having an ETL process to execute on each of these files. However, input to this ETL process accepts only the file name 'File.txt' instead of 'File1.txt, File2.txt..etc..'

Because of size limitations , ETL process won't accept a bigger 'File.txt' file by combining all 'File1.txt, File2.txt..etc..' . This makes bit complex here.

So, one workaround is to run ETL process in loop and feeding it with 'File.txt' on each iteration.

In other words, firstly  'File1.txt' is renamed to 'File.txt' and execute ETL process and end of this process , 'File2.txt' is ready to rename to 'File.txt' and it continues till file's availability.

Whether a Windows batch can be developed to achieve i.e

-Store all available file names (File1,File2) in a temp file
-First execution of ***Batch script renames 'File1.txt' or one which is first in temp file to 'File.txt'.***

------Then I will execute ETL process---[This is not possible to code in Batch script]

***Once ETL process ends, I will recall the same batch script which potentially should point to 2nd file in temp and rename from 'File2.txt' to 'File.txt' and continues till the end of line in temp file.***

I think , including a 'delay' in batch script won't be ideal as ETL process timelines can't be predicted.

Expecting your valuable thoughts

Thanks.

---

I am trying to make requirement as simple as possible.
-This is to be developed in windows .bat script . I don't have a powershell script. Only the basic windows .bat version. :(

1st step :- Create a TempFileList file with all .txt files in a particular directory

2nd step :- Create a Batch file 
               a)Takes input from TempFileList file line by line
               b)Takes 1st file name from TempFileList file (File1.txt) and renames it to File.txt

3rd step :- Once 2b is completed, Batch script needs to wait for .complete file availability [Note :- .complete file will be available only after successful run of a third party application i.e ETL in this context)

4th step :- Upon getting .complete file from Step 3, script needs to look into 2nd file name from TempFileList file and perform rename etc.

Steps 2,3,4 are to be executed in loop and it ends till all filenames in TempFileList file are processed.

Comment: Yes, this would be easy to do. A loop in a batch file, reading filenames from a temp file or getting them dynamically isn't a problem. It could pause to wait for user input to continue to the next file. But what is your question exactly?

Comment: @soja  I have edited the original post with an attempt to make requirements as clear as possible. Please have a look

Comment: Well, you've done a decent job outlining your requirements, but Stack Overflow isn't really a code writing service. I suggest you try something out, and if it's not working, post what you've tried, and ask how to fix it. Here are some tips. Step 1 and 2: use `FOR %%a in (folder\*.txt) do ( echo do stuff with "%%a" here )`. That's your loop. You don't need a temp file. You can use `pause` to manually wait, or you can use `IF NOT EXIST %~na.complete` and `GOTO :label` to wait. That's a start. Try `HELP command` to see all the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

postulat 1 : your ETL traitment use always file named file.txt in C:\temp

postulat 2 : your list files is in c:\templistfile

traitment:

task 1: run a powershell script which copie one file, to end run task 2
command in this script file

```
$pathfileused="C:\temp\file.txt"
$pathfiles="c:\templistfile"
gci $pathfiles -file -filter *.txt | select -First 1 | move-item -Destination $pathfileused -Force
```

task 2: run your processus ETL if file.txt exists, to end run task 1

Comment: On none NTFS drives there isn't necessarily a  sorting. So `-First 1` could be any. The OP isn't clear in that if his ETL-process will `eat` File.txt when finished or if it should be renamed back.

Comment: first is not for sort, is for take one file only... Cause his traitment trait one file by one file

Comment: @Esperento57  have edited the original post with an attempt to make requirements as clear as possible. Please have a look